# Css Center ul li inside nav

Tags: css, html-lists, center, nav

How do I center a horizontal ul with li tags inside a nav:

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="" title=""></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" title=""></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" title=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Center it how? Horizontal , vertical? Do you want to change `<li>` direction?

Here's a codepen that might be what you want.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKdgyd

Comment: Thanks I helped me, but just found a solution to make them horizontal

Comment: You should tell us what you did so when someone has a similar  problem you can help them.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution

html:

```
<div class="main">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="" title=""></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" title=""></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" title=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.main nav {
    width: auto;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
.main nav ul {
    height: auto;
    margin: 21px auto 0 auto;
}

.main nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 19px 0 12px;
    width: 33.3%;
    text-align: center;
}
```